# Fibonacci Series in Turbo Prolog

Tags: turbo-prolog

Trying to do this turbo prolog code but is giving error.

```
predicates
fibo(integer,integer)

clauses
fibo(0,0).
fibo(1,1).
fibo(X,N):-
N>1,
N1=N-1,
N2=N-2,
fibo(F1,N1),
fibo(F2,N2),
F=F1+F2,
write(F),write(",").
```

Comment: It is giving no free variable allowed error on F1 and F2

Comment: The main problem is that you don't reference X. You probably meant `X=F1+F2`.